# how do i remove the decimal point using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I generate a random number when the model is mounted. I want to remove the "0." The 0. and decimal. I tried adding Math.round() but that gives me a NaN. Can someone tell me what I am missing.

```js
new Vue({
el: '#app',
  
  data: { 
      mixNumber:''
  },
  mounted: function(){
  this.myFunction();
  },
  
   methods:{
    myFunction: function () {       
        this.mixNumber = Math.random();
    this.roundNumber=Math.round();
    }   
   }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

 My ID is: {{mixNumber}}
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```js
new Vue({
el: '#app',
  
  data: { 
      mixNumber:'',
      roundNumber: ''
  },
  mounted: function(){
  this.myFunction();
  },
  
   methods:{
    myFunction: function () {       
        this.mixNumber = Math.random();
        this.roundNumber = this.mixNumber.toString().split(".")[1];
    }   
   }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

 My ID is: {{roundNumber}}
 
</div>
```

Comment: or `this.mixNumber.toString().substr(2)`